# Maven TestNG multiple suites in different folders

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, appium, maven

I'm working on a mobile automation task where I need to run test suites in parallel for 3 different iOS apps. Each test suite has its own testng.xml with a  section configured to run on a device.

I tried  `mvn clean test -Dthreads=3 -Dsuites=full path 1 to the suite, full path 2 to the suite, full path 3 to the suite`

Here threads and suites are properties defined in pom.xml.
It looks like the suiteXMLFile in pom.xml cannot take absolute path. It works fine, when I do: mvn clean test -Dthreads=1 -Dsuites=src/test/resources/testng.xml.

How do I run the suites on all 3 devices in parallel with the test suites lying in 3 different folders pointing to 3 different devices?

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

From [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites):

> **5.11.1 - Parallel suites**
>
> This is useful if you are running several suite files (e.g. "java
>   org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml testng2.xml") and you want each of these
>   suites to be run in a separate thread. You can use the following
>   command line flag to specify the size of a thread pool:
>
> ```
> java org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 3 testng1.xml testng2.xml testng3.xml
> ```
>
> The corresponding ant task name is suitethreadpoolsize.

To set this up using Maven Surefire Plugin (as shown [in their examples](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)):

```
</plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <file>${suite1}</file>
            <file>${suite2}</file>
            <file>${suite3}</file>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
              <value>${threads}</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

Then the command line would be:

```
mvn clean test -Dthreads=3 -Dsuite1=<full path 1 to the suite> -Dsuite2=<full path 2 to the suite> -Dsuite3=<full path 3 to the suite>
```